# Angularjs - display 2 lists in a single row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 lists, I want to display the 2 list in single row.

For example:

```
a = [{name: check1, id: 1},{name: check2, id: 2}]

b = [{available: true, id: 1}]
```

In html i want to show them as a single row like.

```
 name   availabilty
check1     true
check2     false
```

Here the list `b` is dynamic the value keeps changing.

So in my front end i have a `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat`.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="list in a">
    {{list.name}} 
    <span ng-repeat="list1 in b" ng-if="list.id==list1.id"> {{list1.availability}} </span>
</div>
```

> So if i dont get the value for `id` how can show it as false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="list in a">
    {{list.name}} 
    <span ng-repeat="list1 in b" > {{list1.id == list.id ?true : false}} </span>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = [{
    name: 'check1',
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'check2',
    id: 2
  }]

  $scope.b = [{
    available: true,
    id: 1
  }]
})
```

```css
.available{
background-color:green;
}
.unavailable{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="list in a">
    {{list.name}}
    <span ng-repeat="list1 in b" ng-class="list1.id == list.id ? 'available' : 'unavailable'"> {{list1.id == list.id ?true : false}} </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks... I have one more question. Is it possible to change the background color based on  `true` or `false`

Comment: what should i use for that `ng-class` or `style`

Comment: you can use both.

Comment: I applied the `ng-class` to `panel` but when the value dynamically changes from true to false the color didnt change.

Comment: please create demo